# Host resolution error while using node-rdkafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm running node-rdkafka as a Node.js application. The consumer hangs indefinitely without pulling any messages from kafka (works on localhost).

Emits the below error,

```
{ Error: Local: Host resolution failure
  origin: 'local',
  message: 'host resolution failure',
  code: -1,
  errno: -1,
  stack: 'Error: Local: Host resolution failure' }
```

The application works to the point of receiving data from kafka. The kafka instance is fine, validated by producing and consuming messages using the console.

Any help with debugging why this is occurring is much appreciated.

Sample consumer code here - https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/consumer-flow.md

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will get better answers if you can post code so that other users can replicate your error.

Comment: URL to sample consumer code added

Comment: Please include in the post itself. [mcve]

Comment: Please include your code, and also details of your network - are you running your code & Kafka on the same machine? EC2? Docker? etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens due to the different networks of your client and broker.

The simple hack is to make host entry of advertised.listeners

For example,
`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`

Then add an entry in `/etc/hosts` with your kafka-broker-IP. For e.g. kafka-borker-IP is `192.168.1.1`

`192.168.1.1 kafka`

You can use `kafkacat` utility to check your broker's IP.

`kafkacat -b kafka:9092 -L`

It will return metadata about the brokers.

You need to check that returned broker's IP is reachable or not from your machine.

For a better understanding of this issue.
You can refer https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Under no circumstances should you ever be editing `/etc/hosts` as a hack to get a connection to a docker container. Instead, set the container up properly so that it has its network configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem when running kafka locally using the quick start instructions from https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

For me, adding the following two lines to `config/server.properties` before starting kafka-server has solved the issue -

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone bumps into this issue in Google Cloud Run: Make sure you have the CPU always allocated to your container. If you switch to on-demand allocation, the lack of CPU power causes this problem.